# How to delete object from array in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem with deleting an `Object` out of an `Array` in `firestore`.
I have this data in firestore:

[image]
[image]

And now I would like to delete e.g the second `Object` out of the `posts Array`.

Code:

```
 deletePic () {
  let docId = `${this.currentUser.uid}`

   fb.usersCollection.doc(docId).update({
     posts: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove()
   })
  .catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
  });
}
```

But I do not know how to define `arrayRemove()`

These are the pictures and each one has a delete button to delete the picture.

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52150545/how-to-add-or-remove-item-to-the-the-existing-array-in-firestore

Answer (score 21, accepted):

EDIT: Warning Do not use my solution as it is more than 3 years old, nowadays there is new solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59745086/6668441 Mine was a pure js one and is a bad pattern.

Can't you use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) ? And then return the new posts array to your `fb.usersCollection` method

```
//deleteId is the id from the post you want to delete
posts.filter(post => post.id !== deleteId);
```

edit : So This should be something like :

```
 deletePic (deleteId) {
  let docId = `${this.currentUser.uid}`

   //deleteId is the id from the post you want to delete

   fb.usersCollection.doc(docId).update({
     posts: posts.filter(post => post.id !== deleteId);
   })
  .catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
  });
}
```

Comment: and where to set the delete()  or arrayRemove()?

Comment: This will store a new array without the post you delete, so this is your `delete()` method

Comment: I updated my answer, then you must get the deleteId from the user click delete button

Comment: the deleteId should contain inside the object or?

Comment: deleteId is something you pass through your function, when the user click on the button you want to get the id of the post or any other information you can use to find the post you want to delete

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179323/discussion-between-fabien-greard-and-lukas).

Comment: If you are working with a big amount of data, you w'll download all the elements to your app just to delete one. It's not optimized.

Comment: I recommend using @Evin1_ method !

Answer (score 57):

You could also use the [arrayRemove](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue.html#public-static-fieldvalue-arrayremove-object...-elements) method from the [FieldValue](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue.html) helper.

```js
docRef.update({
   array: FieldValue.arrayRemove('idToRemove');
});
```

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/better-arrays-in-cloud-firestore.html

Comment: This one work only for simple arrays as ["test","test2"] not if u have array of objects [{},{},{}]

Comment: @PatrikSpišák instead of saving an array convert is to a map before.

Answer (score 15):

You can preform delete of an object in the array by using `arrayRemove` function.
But, you'll need to provide an object.
That object needs to be identical to the one in your doc array on the firestore collection.

For example:

The following code will delete `obj` from `myArray` array,
but only if `obj` exactly exist in that array.

```
const obj = { field1, field2 ... } 

collectionRef.doc(docId).update({
    myArray: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(obj)
})
```

Answer (score 3):

> [Update elements in an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array)
>
> If your document contains an array field, you can use arrayUnion() and
> arrayRemove() to add and remove elements. arrayUnion() adds elements
> to an array but only elements not already present. arrayRemove()
> removes all instances of each given element.

```
// Atomically remove a region from the 'regions' array field.
city_ref.update({u'regions': firestore.ArrayRemove([u'east_coast'])})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Firebase V9 (modular)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array), you can simply import `arrayRemove` from `Firestore` like so:

```js
import { doc, updateDoc, arrayRemove } from 'firebase/firestore';

const docRef = doc(db, 'collection', 'doc');
await updateDoc(docRef, {
  arrayName: arrayRemove('elementName');
});
```