# how to add or remove item to the the existing array in firestore ?

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore has recently add the new new method FieldValue.arrayUnion(value) and FieldValue.arrayRemove(value) but i couldn't find the implementation in flutter cloud_firestore package. Is there any way to achieve this result ?

Firestore addUpdate: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array

Answer (score 11):

Here is the simple example to show how to update the array values. My document have an up voters array to add the user id's who have up-votes the document.

configure firestore, the config details can be copied form your **google-services.json** file

```
   final FirebaseApp app = await FirebaseApp.configure(
    name: 'test',
    options: const FirebaseOptions(
      projectID: 'projid',
      googleAppID: 'appid',
      apiKey: 'api',
      databaseURL: 'your url',
    ),
  );
  final Firestore firestore = Firestore(app: app);

  await firestore.settings(timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled: true);
```

update code using transaction

```
fireStore.runTransaction((Transaction tx) async {
            DocumentSnapshot snapshot =
                await tx.get(widget._document.reference);
            var doc = snapshot.data;
            if (doc['upvoters'].contains('12345')) {
              await tx.update(snapshot.reference, <String, dynamic>{
                'upvoters': FieldValue.arrayRemove(['12345'])
              });
            } else {
              await tx.update(snapshot.reference, <String, dynamic>{
                'upvoters': FieldValue.arrayUnion(['12345'])
              });
            }
          });
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 5):

Update:
And now it seems that it is supported! With the version 0.8.0.

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore

And then use FieldValue.arrayUnion and FieldVale.arrayRemove.

---

There doesn't seems to be a way currently. Please follow the following two github issues:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21148
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20688