# How to read FieldValues of array in Flutter Firestore

Tags: arrays, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to read some fieldvalues of array union from firestore collection documents.

My array looks like this:

[image]

I want to get all the three field values `content`, `timestamp`, `username`.
How can I show retrieve them and show in `Text` widget in flutter? So far I created this using:

```
    Future<void> setAnswer() async {
      String ans = ans_Controller.text;
      FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

      await db.runTransaction((transaction) async {
        DocumentReference qRef =
            db.collection('question').doc(widget.question.id);
        await qRef.update({
          'ans': FieldValue.arrayUnion([
            {
              'content': ans,
              'timestamp': DateTime.now().toString(),
              'username': _currentUser.displayName,
            }
          ])
        });
      });
    }
```

Any help is appreciated,

thank you.

Comment: The code in your question shows how you write this data. What have you tried for **reading it**? Did you check the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#read-data)?

Comment: @Abhishek Please let us know if the above comment helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation which was referred by @RenaudTarnec explains the usage of reading data field values of array union.

To achieve your goal you can follow this flutter Firebase documentation of [reading data.](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#read-data)