# How to delete element of array in Firestore?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to delete the first element of Array.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBdjV.png)

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can by just updating the whole array :

```
yourArray.removeAt(0); //yourArray is the array in the firestore before changing anything
doc("docId").update("Array" : yourArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove an array inside Firebase Firestore. Try the following function:

```
docRef.update({
   array: FieldValue.arrayRemove(''); // Here add your Element ID which you want to remove it.
});
```

`Notice` : This method only works with simple array like `["test","test"]` not array with objects.

Thanks for @Evin1_  in (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59745086/14945696).